# Разработка в Kubernetes - подмена контейнеров для отдельных Dev/QA

Tags: azure, kubernetes

Мы используем Kubernetes для развертывания тестовых окружений. Само окружение - это примерно 40-50 микросервисов + nginx для роутинга входящего траффика. Вызовы к микросервисам есть как внешние (через nginx), так и внутренние (обычный http).

Сейчас каждое тестовое окружение - отдельный namespace, в который задеплоен полный набор микросервисов. Это требует достаточно много памяти, и требует периодического редеплоя каждого тестового окружения (все автоматизировано, но тем не менее). Кроме того, есть накладывает жесткое ограничение на общее количество микросервисов из-за проблем с DSR на windows-нодах - около 300 сервисов в кластере для них предел, это 8 тестовых окружений.

При этом основной кейс тестирования у QA - это master всех микросервисов + 1 измененный.

Вопрос: есть ли более-менее стандартный способ организовать деплоймент так, чтобы экземпляры всех микросервисов, кроме тестируемого, были общими для всех QA окружений.

Конкретные проблемы:

- вызовы к микросервиса должны уходить в на переопределенный в данном тестовом окружении, если он есть. В противном случае - уходить в общий.
- роутинг вызовов должен работать даже для непрямых вызовов - т.е. срабатывать посреди цепочки микросервисов, а не только для первого запроса через nginx (иначе все решалось бы через ingress)

Похожую проблему решал Azure DevSpaces, но его по неопределенным причинам решили закрыть.

Вот примерная схема того, что хотелось бы получить (и что позволял делать Azure DevSpaces):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение уже multi-tenant, и умеет изолировать данные для jonh.s.dev.myapp / dev.myapp по входящему URL.

Проблемные места:

- как изолировать два разных деплоймента / сервиса Reservations (по namespace, как это делали DevSpaces)?
- как перенаправить вызов Bikes -> Reservations без дописывания DNS проверок вида reservations.john.svc.cluster.local ?? reservations.dev.svc.cluster.local в каждый микросервис. Прокидывать информацию вида "top-level вызов был для jonh.s.dev.myapp" приложение уже умеет.

---

Если коротко: есть ли готовые альтернативы закрытому Azure DevSpaces? Общие для k8s или специфические для Azure - не принципиально.

Comment: ¿Это вопрос по веб-разработке? Так или иначе, прежде чем решать поставленный вопрос, вам стоит озадачится другим вопросом: если экземпляры микросервисов (что бы не скрывалось под этим buzzword) будут общие, то не будут ли действия в разных QA окружениях критически влиять друг на друга, порождая трудновоспроизводимые проблемы.

Comment: По-моему, это в принципе невозможно, если сами микросервисы это не поддерживают. 1. то что написал(а) выше @user7860670 - т.е. сетапы с разными сервисами (каждый со своей БД) это не то же, что сетап с одним сервисом (например, хоть одно ограничение уникальности чего либо будет работать по разному в этих двух случаях) 2. каждый вызов из сервиса выполняется в контексте тестового окружения. если сам сервис не запоминает, какое тестовое окружение явилось _причиной_ вызова, только наблюдая снаружи этого определить никак нельзя

Comment: @user7860670 приложение умеет полноценный multi-tenancy, и умеет запросы от account1.app.com, account2.app.com, accountn.app.com через всю цепочку сервисов front -> back1 -> back2 ->db о в разные базы, без влияния друг на друга. Вопрос - есть ли более-менее общепринятый способ зароутить вызов account2.app.com в отдельный деплоймент back1_2, получив цепочку front -> back1_2 -> back2 -> db именно при внешнем вызове по этому URL

Comment: @user7860670 экземпляр микросервиса == Service + deployment с парой подов. в случае AKS DevSpaces это решается подъемом этого набора back1_2_service/back1_2_deployment в отдельном namespace + роутингом траффика в него/из него по наличию хедера (devspace name), который каждый микросервис прокидывает из всех входящих вызовов во все исходящие

Comment: @RomanKonoval каждый сервис знает, в рамках какого окружения к нему пришел вызов, и прокидывает эту информацию во все исходящие вызовы. Вопрос скорее как организовать исходящие вызовы из микросервиса в переопределенный для определенного окружения (если он есть) и в общий (если переопределенного нет), без дописывания вилки с dns lookup в каждый исходящий вызов.

Comment: Если есть поддержка мультитенанси есть, то, что мешает всем сервисам всегда обращаться друг к другу по фиксированому имени `myservice.mydomain`  + информация о тенанте в header-e (или где она там у вас передается) `tenant=X`, а обратный прокси на входе перенаправляет запрос на `X.myservice.mydomain`, если для `X`  `myservice` подменили, или на `master.myservice.mydomain` если не подменяли. При деплойменте тестового окружения нужно добавлять с высоким приоритетом правила для сервисов, которые в окружении заменены. Что я упускаю?

Comment: @RomanKonoval да, все правильно - именно такой подход мы сейчас пытаемся реализовать (с небольшой разницей - реверс прокси можно сделать один на все сервисы. devspaces делал это через sidecar-контейнеры c реверс прокси поверх каждого сервиса). Основной минус - это практически удваивает длину цепочки вызовов. Я пытаюсь понять: (1) есть ли альтернативы удвоению цепочки и (2) есть ли готовые решения, или полуготовые (на ingress?), чтобы не писать прокси и управление им с нуля.

Answer (score 2):

Если можно изменить сервисы, чтоб имя тенанта передавалось как поддомен, т.е. `tenantX.serviceY`, то можно легко реализовать все в DNS.

Нужно переключиться на использование [CoreDNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns). Там включить плагин для, собственно, kubernetes и [rewrite](https://coredns.io/plugins/rewrite/). Rewrite позволяет изменить входящий DNS запрос по правилам. Добавляем его первым, чтоб он работал до `kubernetes`.

Дальше добавляем статические правила типа `*.serviceY` -> `serviceY.master.cluster.local` в самом конце. А при деплое вначале добавляем правила типа `tenantX.serviceY` -> `serviceY.tenantX.cluster.local`, если `serviceY` заменен в окружении `tenantX`.

Comment: Хорошее решение. Есть способ уйти от ручной правки конфига CoreDNS? под него вроде нет операторов, которые позволяли бы определять rewrite без правки общего конфига?

Comment: Похоже что нет способа, разве что написать свой плагин к CoreDNS. Можно чуть улучшить жизнь используя плагины `reload` и `import`, чтоб структурировать конфигурацию, и отделить неизменную часть конфига от изменяемой и чтоб изменения автоматически подхватывались.